# Is Function overriding automatically done by compiler

Tags: c++

**Is  Function Overriding done automatically by the compiler?**
I know that in case of two function,which may or may not be in same class,with same name and same parameter overriding happens.But other than that the concept is still unclear to me.I guess i am confused a bit between function overriding and overloading.As if it is not automatically done then why are they different?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: what do you mean with "automatically"? Sloppy speaking "overriding" is just a term for the situation when you provide the same method that does something different. All the compiler has to do is to choose the right method to call

Comment: by automatically i mean that i dont have to define to compiler what to do in case of overriding.It "chooses" the right method by itself. that is it has a build in ability to choose.

Answer (score -1):

**Overloading** happens when you change the original types for the arguments in the signature of a method.

**Overriding** happens when you change the original definition of a method

Comment: Define "happens" in context to your answer.

Comment: takes place, occur.